# Expose Public API

Tags: apex, webservices

Is it possible expose a public API using which users across the internet will be able to use it to create records in my dev edition instance. ?

Also can someone tell me some tools available which I can use to mock this API callout ?

Comment: What do you mean, "mock" the callout?

Comment: I mean some sort of client tool for calling the APEX webservice...Similar to how we can run queries against Server DB from a remote client

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want users to access data without authentication, you would generally use Force.com Sites.

If you would like to expose an API, check out this article: [Public RESTful Web Services on Force.com Sites](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2012/02/quick-tip-public-restful-web-services-on-force-com-sites.html)